# resizing window with 2 divs inline-block on the same line trigger weird behavior

Tags: html, css

When i resize my window to a smaller size, the first div goes down. It looks like it happens when the text of the second div break to a new line due to the resize of its box.

I don't understand why the first div is not staying at the top. It's not like i put a vertical align bottom on the container..

I'm aware of `flex-box` but i need to use inline-block in this project and i shouldn't have to use `float` in this situation, it should work without it..

https://jsfiddle.net/ezp0j7fu/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT </div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT  RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  line-height: 0px;
}

.container {
  background: black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

div.left {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

div.right {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've see this many times with in-line blocks. While I can't explain to you exactly why this happens (maybe someone with more indepth CSS knowledge can englighten us) to fix it you need only add a float property to the `div.left` tag. Then your left div and right div will both be at the top.

```
div.left {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: indeed it works.. thank you

Comment: @Owow while this works, it doesn't really fix you issue because you no more have inline-block element when you float them. The correct solution is to consider vertical-align if you want to keep the use of inline-block (check the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is what I meant about someone with more indepth knowledge of CSS explaining things. I guess I wasn't aware that a float property overrides the inline-block property. I've alwasy been a hack at CSS.